# Formatting decimal number for any location

Tags: android, locale, number-formatting

I'm trying to format a decimal number for display that presents it self in the format of the location the device is in.  I also want this decimal number to round to the nearest 10th and not display the 10th place if it is ".0".

I think I'm close.  What I current have is this:

```
NumberFormat numberFormat = NumberFormat.getInstance(getResources().getConfiguration().locale);

if (numberFormat instanceof DecimalFormat) {
    ((DecimalFormat)numberFormat).setDecimalSeparatorAlwaysShown(true);
    ((DecimalFormat)numberFormat).applyPattern("0.#");
}

myText.setText(numberFormat.format(myValue));
```

However, if I have a number greater than 1,000 `ex: 1000.5`, the `TextView` will display `1000.5` instead of `1,000.5` (I am in the USA).

Could someone explain to me why?

Answer (score 0):

You should call [setGrouping(boolean)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html#setGroupingUsed(boolean)) to make sure grouping is turned on.

```
NumberFormat numberFormat = NumberFormat.getInstance(getResources().getConfiguration().locale);

if (numberFormat instanceof DecimalFormat) {
    final DecimalFormat df = (DecimalFormat)numberFormat;
    df.setDecimalSeparatorAlwaysShown(true);
    df.setGroupingUsed(true);
    df.applyPattern("0.#");
}

myText.setText(numberFormat.format(myValue));
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I followed your example, but the TextView is still displaying "1000.5".  [link](http://i.imgur.com/NMMFyBa.png)